# Change label (x-axis, y-axis) font size of already inserted eps figure in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, floats, labels, eps

Just wondering if there is a possibility of changing the font size of the x-axis and y-axis of an eps figure.

I tried `\fontsize{15}{12}\selectfont`, but it did not work at all.

Thank you very much in advance...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Was the eps file that contains an x-axis and a y-axis created by TeX and friends? Please advise. If it was not, your posting may be off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Mico Packages like `psfrag` or `overpic` can be used to solve the problem, therefore the question is not off-topic.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Thanks for providing this information -- I, for one, wasn't aware of it. It would still be helpful, though, if the OP provided a bit more information about the eps file(s) in question, right?

Comment: @Mico Yes, the best strategy depends on the PostScript file, whether it can be regenerated, how it was generated, how the text/fonts are placed there (as font, as drawing commands without glyphs, as bitmap, ...). In some cases, the PostScript file can even be edited directly, provided there are some basic knowledge about PostScript operators at least.